# How can I eliminate the inline styles included by default with the Genesis framewrok?

Tags: genesis-theme-framework

I have created a child theme in the Genesis framework. I have created all of my style rules, however, in the markup, Genesis adds a few inline rules by default that I would like to eliminate.

The rules look like this:

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
<style type="text/css">
    #header { background: url(http://localhost/h.jpg) no-repeat; }
</style>
```

These inline styles are creating my last remaining problem. I've reviewed the docs and tried to find if there are any hooks or parameters that I can alter, but have not found any.

How can i get rid of them across the entire child theme?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The first inline CSS is added by WordPress automatically when you are logged in and viewing the front end. It is part of the CSS for the WordPress adminbar.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
* html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
```

For the second part of the inline CSS I would check around in Genesis for add_action('wp_header' ..

Answer (score 0):

Add a class on **header.php**

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="top">
```

and add css on **style.css**

```
.top{
    margin:0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just comment out what you dont want by adding `/*` and closing it with `*/` like this

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
/*html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
 html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }*/
</style>
<style type="text/css">
/*#header { background: url(http://localhost/h.jpg) no-repeat; }*/
</style>
```

Notice how they become grey and inactive

Comment: genesis does not expose CSS in the traditional matter, so simply commenting it out is not possible. My goal is to determine how to disable the functionality.

Answer (score -1):

The best way I've found to remove that white space (it's not caused by the admin bar) is to search out this css in style.css:

## page {

```
margin: 2em auto;
max-width: 1000px;
```

}

and switch the 2em to 0em or some variation of the same. That will remove the white space.